# How to determine hyperparameters separately for multiple targets within sklearn's GridSearchCV

Tags: scikit-learn

In scikit learn, I would like to cross-validate the best lambda hyperparameter separately for each of multiple targets using ridge regression. Is this only possible by running separate univariate models or can this also be done via a multivariate model?

So, this is the code I'm currently running:

```
parameters = np.logspace(-10, 10, num=100)
estimator  = Ridge(fit_intercept=False, normalize=False)
cv         = KFold(n_splits=10)

clf        = GridSearchCV(estimator, {'alpha': parameters}, scoring='r2', n_jobs=-1, cv=cv, return_train_score=True)
clf.fit(X, Y)

mean_score = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
```

This will give me an r2 value for each lambda value across all targets, whereas I'm looking for r2 for each lambda value per target.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by `across all targets` and `per target`?

Comment: @AnantKumar Assuming that I have 200 targets, 100 hyperparameters and 10 data splits, `mean_score` will yield 10 x 100 values, so I don't get a mean score for each target. What I would be interested in is a 10 x 100 x 200 dimensional matrix where each target has its own hyperparameter performance profile.